# Sum of ArrayList for different types

Tags: java, arraylist

Is it possible to write a single method `total` to do a sum of all elements of an `ArrayList`, where it is of type `<Integer>` or `<Long>`?

I cannot just write

```
public long total(ArrayList<Integer> list)
```

and

```
public long total(ArrayList<Long> list)
```

together as there will be an error of erasure, and `Integer` does not automatically extends to `Long` and vice versa... but the code inside is identical!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Yes, you can implement such a method, since both `Integer` and `Long` extend [`Number`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Number.html). For example you can use a [wildcard type](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/wildcards.html) for the list element type:

```
public static long total(List<? extends Number> list) {
    long sum = 0;
    for (Number n : list) {
        if (!(n instanceof Byte || n instanceof Short || n instanceof Integer || n instanceof Long)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }
        sum += n.longValue();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

This only works for the integral types however, since the `sum` variable and the return value are of type `long`.

Ideally you would like to be able to also use the method with `Float`s and `Double`s and return an object of the same type as the list element type, but this is not easy to do for two reasons:

1. The only thing you can do with a `Number` is to get its value as one of the primitive number types. You can not sum two of them in a number dependent way.
2. It is not possible to create a 0-object of the right class.

---

**EDIT:** *Much later...*

Just for fun, lets do this in a nice way for Java. The thing you have to do is to manually provide the two operations mentioned above. A kind of value with two such operation is usually called a [monoid](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monoid) in the context of algebra and functional programming.

The problem can be solved by creating objects that represent the monoid operations:

```
interface MonoidOps<T> {
    T id();
    T op(T o1, T o2);
}
```

The `total` method can now be implemented to take an object of this type in addition to the list:

```
public static <T> T total(List<T> list, MonoidOps<T> ops) {
    T sum = ops.id();
    for (T e : list) {
        sum = ops.op(e, sum);
    }
    return sum;
}
```

To provide `MonoidOps` implementations for the numeric classes, lets create a simple helper class:

```
class SimpleMonoidOps<T> implements MonoidOps<T> {
    private final T idElem;
    private final BinaryOperator<T> operation;

    public SimpleMonoidOps(T idElem, BinaryOperator<T> operation) {
        this.idElem = idElem;
        this.operation = operation;
    }

    public T id() {
        return idElem;
    }

    public T op(T o1, T o2) {
        return operation.apply(o1, o2);
    }
}
```

The `MonoidOps` implementations can now be written neatly like this:

```
static final MonoidOps<Integer> INT_MONOID_OPS = new SimpleMonoidOps<>(0, Integer::sum);
static final MonoidOps<Double> DOUBLE_MONOID_OPS = new SimpleMonoidOps<>(0.0, Double::sum);
```

And the `total` method would be called like this:

```
int sum = total(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3), INT_MONOID_OPS);
```

Comment: Learn something new everyday :) Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can also use streams in Java 8

```
public static <T extends Number> long sumList(List<T> list)
{
    return list.stream().mapToLong(a -> a.longValue()).sum();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Java´s generics for this

```
public <T extends Number> T total(List<T> list) {
    T sum = 0;
    for (T n : list) {
        sum += n.longValue();
    }
    return sum;
}
```

Knowing that `T` will always be a `Number`, things are simplified. However, this solution could work also for `String`s, if necessary. The only change would be in the `extends` part.

Comment: I guess it is better to always return `long` and not the generic type `T`, because OP already expects `long` and it prevents an overflow a bit more.

Comment: This won't compile at `T sum = 0;` and `sum += n;`.

Comment: @Reimeus Not anymore :D. Maybe he will fix it.

Comment: This does not work, unfortunately. You cannot assign a `0` literal to a variable of type `T` since there is no way for the compiler to know which type it should be converted to.